# Set up laptop as access point

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, nmcli

I want to use my laptop as an access point to extend coverage in my house. The laptop is connected via ethernet to the router that also provides the rest of the house with wifi. I can start a hotspot quite easily using Network Manager:

```
nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid my-ssid password 12345678
```

However, the problem is that devices connected to it get ip address from the DHCP server running on the laptop. Ideally I want to use the same ssid as the one used by my router and have the laptop simply as a bridge, so for example clients would get their ip address from the DHCP running on the router. How can that be accomplished?